# Why does the button at the end of password field show my password?

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 8, there is some button at the end of the input field that shows my password.
It appears as if I have locked my Windows.

Is there some way to turn it off?

**Picture**

[image]

That button before ->

Comment: This is not possible to disable.  Its likely a feature that is optional, in that, you don't have to actually use it.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok thanks for the information. It's more like kids on school will try to click it ..  So I was looking a way to disable it

Comment: Hey thanks for selecting my wrong answer as right ;) Jokes aside: There is a way to disable this. It's done by GPO. You can find the Setting by opening the local group policy editor (start - run - gpedit.msc) and then find the policy under: Computer - Administrative Templates -  Windows Components - Credential User Interface -  Do not display the password reveal button. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is the password hint.
Go to System Preferences - User Accounts - Your Account - Change Password.
There are two fields for your password and one for the password hint.
Could it be that you entered your password there, in the hint field?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Now that we talk about the same thing ;):

You can find the Setting by opening the local group policy editor (start - run - gpedit.msc) and then find the policy under: **Computer - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Credential User Interface - Do not display the password reveal button**

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer, but I ment something else. I make a picture today with my phone because printscreen won't work.